# How do I resize labels, text fields, etc. in the IntelliJ Java Swing form?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

So, for example, I created a text field.
[image]

Tried to resize it
[image]

But once I release the mouse, it gets back to its original size
[image]

So how do I do it? How do I resize elements? And yes, I tried to change the minimum size, maximum size, preferred size but it does not work either, nothing happens.

Comment: Specify the minimum/preferred/maximum sizes in the properties.

Comment: Don't use an IDE to build your forms. Instead learn how to design forms using a layout manager. The knowledge will be portable even is you use a different IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `setLayout(null)` on the parent or `setPreferredSize` on the components, either of which will allow you to resize your Components. But the best answer is to set your Font size to a larger size (`setFont(...)`) which will cause them to become bigger (have larger values in getPreferredSize) automatically.

```
JTextField tf = ...;
tf.setFont(tf.getFont().deriveFont(tf.getFont().getSize() * 2));
```

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw You are right of course. But Swing is IMO almost entirely a learning tool these days... so rarely used in business production development, so I think its alright just for messing around

Comment: yeah i guess that makes sense.